# Normal distribution curve and random number in LUA

Tags: math, random, lua, numbers, normal-distribution

So say I have a range of numbers 1-1000. math.random(1,1000) would give me an equal chance of getting each number. Instead of this, I want to make a distribution curve so that the chance of getting 1 equals the chance of getting 1000 but the chance of getting 500 for example is much more common. How would I go about making this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function norm1000()
   local x 
   repeat
      x = math.ceil(math.log(1/math.random())^.5*math.cos(math.pi*math.random())*150+500)
   until x >= 1 and x <= 1000
   return x
end
```

Comment: Please include more than just code in your answer. Where did you get the formula you're using and how closely does it approximate a normal distribution?

Comment: @StefanFabian - `Where did you get the formula you're using` - This formula is widely used, BTW it's a good exercise to mathematically prove its correctness.   `how closely does it approximate a normal distribution` - It depends on the `math.random()` quality on your system.